# Definition of Ancestral Eudicot?

Tags: plant-physiology

I am wondering what are examples of ancestral eudicots which can be purchased from an aquarium store, and or grocery flower store.

Comment: Have you tried googling this?

Comment: yes. that would be my first go to ...

Comment: and what did you find? Tell us a bit, so we can help elaborate!

Comment: All I found was the definition of ancestral (in terms of a cladogram). I mean, there are several plants which can be purchased from aquarium and grocery stores. However, since I am not a plant biologist it is hard for me to even guess how to go about figuring which ones are ancestral eudicots

Comment: If someone could tell me the answer, and how to go about figuring something like this in the future, I would really appreciate it.